# Add field to subdocument from document returned from query

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to add a field to the returned subdocument like this:

```
{
"type": "product",
"code": "abc",
"team": "A1",
"modules": [{
        "type": "module",
        "code": "cde"
        //Add a new field here
    }]
}
```

I can add new field in document by `Document.append()` but can't add to the subdocument.

Here is my Java code:

```
BasicDBObject query  = new BasicDBObject("code", "abc");
AggregateIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    new Document("$match", query),
    new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0).append("type", 1)
                                               .append("code", 1)
                                               .append("team", 1)
                                               .append("modules", 1)
                                               ),
    new Document("$sort", new Document("code", 1))
));

mongoCursor = findIterable.iterator(); 

while(mongoCursor.hasNext()){ 
    Document document = mongoCursor.next();
}
```

Can someone give some help please? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html - Check this to parse through and append

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! But the document I using is this: http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html#toBsonDocument-java.lang.Class-org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry-
Is it possible to convert from org.bson.document to the one you mentioned?

Comment: Why do you need aggregation ? Do you just want to add a new field to the sub document and update the collection ?